# Using CASE statement in where clause having parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I am creating oracle report where if the user inputs true or false, the respective values should go to parameter. if user inputs All, then both true and false should go to parameters.

I used the following case statements in 3 ways. all of them show missing keyword error. could you please help me resolve this.

```
WHERE "EngExec Status" = ((:eng_exec_status = 'True' and "EngExec Status" = 'True') 
                           OR (:eng_exec_status = 'False' AND "EngExec Status" = 'False') 
                           OR (:eng_exec_status = 'All' AND  ("EngExec Status" = 'True' OR "EngExec Status"= 'False')))
                         
WHERE "EngExec Status" IN (CASE 
                               WHEN (:eng_exec_status) = 'True' THEN "EngExec Status"= 'True'
                               WHEN (:eng_exec_status) = 'False' THEN "EngExec Status"= 'False'
                               ELSE "EngExec Status" IN ('True', 'False')  
                           END) 

WHERE "EngExec Status" IN (CASE 
                               WHEN (:eng_exec_status) = 'All' THEN "EngExec Status" IN ('True','False')
                               ELSE (:eng_exec_status)   
                           END)
```

Comment: Because case is an *expression*, it should return a scalar. Oracle have no Boolean datatype, so `case` cannot return `"EngExec Status"= 'True'`

Comment: And another problem: if it would have Boolean, what do you expect to get for such filter: `where "EngExec Status" = "EngExec Status"= 'True'`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want something simple like

```
WHERE ( :eng_exec_status = 'All' )
   OR ( :eng_exec_status = "EngExec Status" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet:

```sql
WHERE "EngExec Status" = ((:eng_exec_status = 'True' and "EngExec Status" = 'True') 
                           OR (:eng_exec_status = 'False' AND "EngExec Status" = 'False') 
                           OR (:eng_exec_status = 'All' AND  ("EngExec Status" = 'True' OR "EngExec Status"= 'False')))
```

Fails as you have `WHERE column_value = (<boolean_expression>)` and that is not valid syntax. You can just remove the `"EngExec Status" =`  at the start:

```sql
WHERE (:eng_exec_status = 'True'  AND "EngExec Status" = 'True') 
OR    (:eng_exec_status = 'False' AND "EngExec Status" = 'False') 
OR    (:eng_exec_status = 'All'   AND ("EngExec Status" = 'True' OR "EngExec Status"= 'False'))
```

---

The second snippet has the `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE 
WHEN (:eng_exec_status) = 'True' THEN "EngExec Status"= 'True'
WHEN (:eng_exec_status) = 'False' THEN "EngExec Status"= 'False'
ELSE "EngExec Status" IN ('True', 'False')  
END
```

It should have the syntax:

```sql
CASE WHEN comparison_expr THEN return_expr [...] ELSE expr END
```

And [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96):

> For both simple and searched `CASE` expressions, all of the *`return_exprs`* must either have the same data type (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, or `NVARCHAR2`, `NUMBER`, `BINARY_FLOAT`, or `BINARY_DOUBLE`) or must all have a numeric data type.

Your return values do not have any of those data types and you have put a comparison expression in instead.

Oracle complains about a " missing keyword error" as it expects either the `WHEN`, `ELSE` or `END` keywords after the `"EngExec Status"` in the `THEN` and `ELSE` clauses (since it is not valid to put a comparison expression in that location so the `=` and `IN` operators and the expression following them are invalid syntax).

---

Your third snippet fails for a similar reason to the second.

---

If you have a `CHECK` constraint on the `"EngExec Status"` column to restrict the value to either `'True'` or `'False'` then you can simplify the `WHERE` filter to:

```sql
WHERE :eng_exec_status = "EngExec Status" OR :eng_exec_status = 'All'
```

If you do not have a `CHECK` constraint to restrict the values then you can use:

```sql
WHERE "EngExec Status" IN ('True', 'False')
AND   (:eng_exec_status = "EngExec Status" OR :eng_exec_status = 'All')
```